# MySQL - Which of these both is the better index?

Tags: mysql

I have a website with a database of 2,4 million entries. Now I want to use mod_rewrite to produce clear URLs like example.com/this-is-a-beautiful-url. To recognize which URL belongs to which page I want to build a URL-table which refers to the website's content. Like "this-url-example" belongs to the post with the ID 123. 
Now 2 friends are telling me 2 different ways to build this table and I don't know which one is the best.

1. Advice: "Make a MD5 hash of the URLs and save them in a binary field with an index".
2. Advice: "Simply save the urls in plain text and put an index on it".

Which method would provide faster select-queries? Do you have another advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Go for a compromise, have urls as
sitename.com/12345/clean-url-format

You have both keywords in a readable URL and the identified which you can use to fetch the row by the primary key for speed.

It would be reasonable to redirect urls without the text part to the canonical version with it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But having the ID inside the URL wouldn't be beneficial for SEO.

Comment: It would have a) absolutely no negative effect b) solve performance issues on text field lookups

Comment: @Crayl - Why would it not be beneficial for SEO? As long as you don't garble together the ID and the [slug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_%28web_publishing%29) it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

MD5 Hash was designed for data comparison purposes. I.e. checking that a password is valid or that a file remains unchanged.

If you plan on being able to change and modify the URL (for search engine optimization purposes) I would stick to Plain text.

Also if you want to create Mod Rewrite Commands (in your HTACCESS) file - it will need to be plain text to enable you to link that URL with a particular page.

Comment: The way it would work with the MD5 hash is that the [slug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_%28web_publishing%29) would be hashed when a page is requests and then you would search in the DB by hash. The alternative mentioned would just be to search by the slug.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use either mysql or md5 hashing.  Instead, use a key-value store such as [dbm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/dbm) or [leveldb](http://leveldb.org/).  If you are using Apache's `mod_rewrite`, it has a feature, [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) that can read the keys and values directly from a dbm db, or by calling an external program.  The type can be `sdbm`, [`gdbm`](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/), `ndbm` or `db` ([Berkeley DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB)), and apache includes a program, [httxt2dbm](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/httxt2dbm.html), to create the database.  If you do want to use MySQL, RewriteMap can do that as well with the dbd option, and [mod_dbd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dbd.html).  Performance-wise, using a hash index on MySQL should be similar to Berkley DB.